# Can't install Python on Termux 0.118.0 - encountering 'Unable to locate package' error. Any solutions?

Tags: python, android, termux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYtSf.jpg)How to fix the error "Unable to locate package" this happens when i try to install python

I want to install python on termux 0.118.0 but anyway when i try to install python, python2 python-pip i get this error, how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.